# react native, как вызвать метод по клику

Tags: react-native, reactjs

Столкнулся с проблемой:
необходимо спрятать клавиатуру по клику вне textInput.. но проблема такая что клик никак не могу определить, потому как он работает только на TouchableHighlight, а мне нужно конкретно по координатам определить, и проверить есть ли там textinput. Есть такая возможность в react native?

Answer (score 2):

На всякий случай, оставлю это здесь:

```
import {Keyboard} from "react-native"; 
<TextInput onBlur={()=>Keyboard.dismiss()} />
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы пожалуйста пояснить, как ваш фрагмент кода отвечаает на вопрос ТС.

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой: необходимо спрятать клавиатуру по клику вне textInput..  -> разве вопрос не в том, чтобы спрятать клавиатуру? Что касается части про " конкретно по координатам определить, и проверить есть ли там textinput" - то координаты разве не излишни в данном случае? Есть textinput - прячем клавиатуру, нет textinput - не прячем.